# Bring activity to front when required (when app is in background)

Tags: android

I have a requirement to bring up an activity to the front for a couple of different scenarios, however, no matter what I try, the activity remains in the background.

This I thought for certain should work:

```
this.startActivity(Intent(activity, MainActivity.class)
.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT));
```

Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: did you try to use BroadcastReceiver ??

Comment: I did. The problem isn't that the Activity is not getting the code, the problem is I want to bring the same activity to the front that was  paused.

Comment: You want to bring your task (your app) to the front. `REORDER_TO_FRONT` just rearranges the activtes within a task. To bring your task to the front please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29769255/769265